# HTML en functions.php de WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando meter un banner de cookies HTML en el archivo functions.php de WordPress para que se muestre cuando se carga. Este archivo está dentro de un tema hijo, no el original o padre.

C:\xampp\htdocs\circulogastronomico\wp-content\themes\oceanwp-child

[image: localizacion]

El functions.php queda de la siguiente manera tal como me han indicado pero tampoco funciona:

```
<?php

function enqueue_styles_child_theme() {

$parent_style = 'oceanwp-style';
$child_style  = 'ocean-child-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style,
            get_template_directory_uri() . 'ocean/style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( $child_style,
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
            );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_child_theme' );

add_action('wp_footer', 'bannerCookies');

function bannerCookies(){
?>
  <h1>HOLA PRUEBA</h1>
<?php
}
```

Como digo, esto es un functions.php creado en localhost y en un child theme. Esto probado en el tema padre si que funciona. Entiendo que es alguna dependencia que falla ya que lo único que hay en el functions.php del child theme a mi entender es la herencia del style.css del padre pero nada mas.

Comment: Miro mal o miro dos puntos en el functions..php ?

Comment: Madre de Dios. Correcto. Además me ha solucionado todo lo relacionado con el estilo y de más. Dos días llevo peleándome con códigos de ya no se cuantas páginas distintas, revisando puntos, comas, rutas. Resulta que se me ha colado un punto al nombrar el archivo. Que rabia y que alegría a la vez de por fin ver la luz. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso el siguiente Snippet. Mira si te sirve. En mi caso va de maravilla

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'BBT_cookie_n');

function BBT_cookie_n(){
?>
    <script>
        function setCookie_notice(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie_notice(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function refuse(e) {
            setCookie_notice("c_notice_webSite", "false", 1);
            document.getElementById("cooki_n").style.display = "none";
        }

        function  acepte(e) {
            setCookie_notice("c_notice_webSite", "true", 1);
            document.getElementById("cooki_n").style.display = "none";
        }

        document.addEventListener("readystatechange", cargarEventos, false);

        function cargarEventos(evento) {
            if(document.readyState=="interactive"){
                document.getElementById("cooki_n_refuse_button").addEventListener("click", refuse);
                document.getElementById("cooki_n_accept_button").addEventListener("click", acepte);
                if(getCookie_notice("c_notice_webSite") == "")
                {
                    document.getElementById("cooki_n").style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        div.cooki_n {
            font-size: 13px;
            display: none;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 20px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 17px 27px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Arial, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
            z-index: 9999;
        }

        div.cooki_n .cooki_n_container {
            display: flex;
        }

        .cooki_n_container .cooki_n_text_container {
            width: 70%;
            text-align: right;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .cooki_n_container .cooki_n_buttons_container {
            width: 30%;
        }

        div.cooki_n_container span.cooki_n_buttons_container a {
            margin-right: 9px;
        }

        div.cooki_n a.cooki_n_button {
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Arial, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 13px;
            letter-spacing: 0.25px;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            touch-action: manipulation;
            white-space: nowrap;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            text-shadow: none;
            border: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #fd7803;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 8.5px 10px;
            line-height: 1;
        }

        div.cooki_n a.cooki_n_button:hover {
            background-color: #af5302;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1024px) {
            div.cooki_n .cooki_n_container {
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .cooki_n_container .cooki_n_text_container {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .cooki_n_container .cooki_n_buttons_container {
                margin-top: 4px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <div id="cooki_n" class="cooki_n" aria-label="Cookie Notice BBT_webSite" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)">
        <div class="cooki_n_container" style="color: #fff">
            <span id="cooki_n_text_container" class="cooki_n_text_container">
                Usamos cookies para garantizar que le brindemos la mejor experiencia
                en nuestro sitio web. Si continúa utilizando este sitio, asumiremos
                que está de acuerdo con ello.
            </span>

            <span id="cooki_n_buttons" class="cooki_n_buttons_container">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="cooki_n_accept_button" class="cooki_n_button cooki_n_accept_button" aria-label="Boton Aceptar Cookies">
                    Aceptar
                </a>

                <a href="#" id="cooki_n_refuse_button" class="cooki_n_button cooki_n_accept_button" aria-label="Boton Rechazar Cookies">
                    Rechazar
                </a>

                <a href="https://webSite.es/politica-de-cookies/" target="_blank" id="cooki_n_more_info" class="cooki_n_more_info cooki_n_button" aria-label="Política de Cookies">
                    Política de Cookies
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Comment: La wp_head función se ejecuta en el header del tema, por lo que aunque funciona, poner html en esa parte es incorrecto, lo mejor es que uses wp_body_open o wp_footer, funciones que si se ejecutan dentro del body y no en el header.

Comment: @OCHOA entiendo el codigo. Lo probaré. Lo que intentaba de todas formas es añadirlos desde un documento js externo.

Comment: @JefferzonBol tiene razón, he cambiado `wp_head` por `wp_footer` en el Snnipet anterior.

Comment: @OCHOA no funciona. He reeditado la pregunta añadiendo tu código a mi functions.php para ver que falla porque no lo veo. He cambiado "wp_header" por "wp_footer", "wp_body_open" como comenta Jefferzon Bol y de ninguna de las maneras. Tiene que haber algo en el functions.php que no me funciona y no veo.

Comment: @JoseL. ni siquiera analizaste el código, solo le hiciste copy paste :-S así no se vale men, el código funciona, pero ponle un poco de análisis y si al final del día no le encuentras, te diré que hacer (eso en base al nuevo código agregado a tu pregunta, el cual es idéntico al de mi respuesta).... Disclaimer: No es que no quiera dar la respuesta, estoy fomentando el auto aprendizaje, lo digo por si alguien más quiere dar la respuesta...

Comment: @OCHOA tal cual. Llevo 2 días con esto y no doy en la clave. Si es que he visto en varios sitios como se hace y lo estoy haciendo. Incluso solo meter un simple echo<h1> para probar pero nada. Lo he puesto arriba, lo he puesto abajo, actualizado cache ... Si me dices que ahí hay algo mal que yo no veo lo seguiré revisando hoy.

Comment: @JoseL. has editado mi respuesta en lugar de la tuya. Mira, el código que puse ha funcionado en otras webs, voy a preguntarte algo que aunque parezca ilógico puede que sea la respuesta. Cambiaste la palabra `webSite` por tu dominio?? en mi Snnipet utilizo 5 veces esa palabra (incluidas las que son precedidas por un guion bajo), me imagino que si cambias `webSite` por `tudominio` sin nada de puntos ni nada, te funcionará. Si no funciona entonces serás el primero al que no le haya funcionado y lo probare en otra web que tenga por ahí... Te espero en el [chat] ahora mismo.

Comment: No quería decir que el problema fuese tu codigo, disculpa. Reedite tu respuesta equivocadamente pero sólo quería mostrar el código que he sacado de varias fuentes y de WordPress para añadir contenido al functions.php. Como se ve, solo contiene un <h1> que tampoco se crea. Es esto lo que no consigo averiguar. Yo ya tengo un banner creado y su script que funciona en una web creada sin WordPress perfectamente. Copiar el tuyo ha sido desesperación por comparar e intentar averiguar pero esque no hay manera. No se por qué no se muestra ni el h1

Comment: @Jefferzon Bol he reeditado porque he concretado un poco. El código añadido al tema padre funciona, donde no funciona es en el functions.php del child theme. Entiendo que es alguna dependencia o algo que falta pero no encuentro nada al respecto.